Trouble with .NET Functionality in FactoryTalk Optix Software
it's my first time here in this forum. I work with FactoryTalk Optix software to program HMI. It supports .NET. I'm not familiar with C#, but I asked ChatGPT about it to create. I have no errors after building, but nothing happens. I'm trying to check if var1 is equal to "3" then change it to "10", otherwise return the value of var1. Var1 is of string datatype. Here's my code:
#region Using directives

using System;
using UAManagedCore;
using OpcUa = UAManagedCore.OpcUa;
using FTOptix.HMIProject;
using FTOptix.Alarm;
using FTOptix.UI;
using FTOptix.NativeUI;
using FTOptix.NetLogic;
using FTOptix.Recipe;
using FTOptix.SQLiteStore;
using FTOptix.Store;
using FTOptix.RAEtherNetIP;
using FTOptix.DataLogger;
using FTOptix.CoreBase;
using FTOptix.CommunicationDriver;
using FTOptix.Retentivity;
using FTOptix.System;
using FTOptix.EventLogger;
using FTOptix.SerialPort;
using FTOptix.Core;

#endregion

public class RuntimeNetLogic1 : BaseNetLogic
{

//Copy
    public override void Start()
    {
        // Get the variable
        IUAVariable var1 = Project.Current.GetVariable("Model/var1");
        // Check if var1 exists and its value is a string
        if (var1 != null && var1.DataType == OpcUa.DataTypes.String)
        {
            // Convert the value to string
            string var1Value = var1.Value.ToString();

            // Check if var1Value is "3"
            if (var1Value == "3")
            {
                // If var1Value is "3", change it to "10"
                var1.SetValue("10");
            }
            else
            {
                // Log the value of var1
                Log.Info("Value of var1: " + var1Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Log a message indicating that var1 is not a valid string variable
            Log.Warning("Variable var1 does not exist or is not a string type.");
        }
    }

    public override void Stop()
    {
        // Insert code to be executed when the user-defined logic is stopped
    }
}


No errors
The path is correct to the corresponding variable
Tried to change the initial value of var1 to 3 or Null nothing happend


Fixed a little bit of the code formatting.  Mind that I commented the "Copy" line of which I think it's a copy&paste artifact? It would break your compilation, so you might want to either correct it if it is something actually in your code or remove it.

"but I asked ChatGPT about it to create" - Yeah, don't. ChatGPT does know as much C# as you. It just has more templates to copy from. Instead, take the time to learn your tools.

If your Log doesn't contain that Info, nor the Warning messages, then SetValue should have been executed. Now if you don't see an effect, it can mean different things: 1. The Start() method has not been executed in the first place. -> Check by either debugging and stepping through or put a Log in every path of that method. 2. SetValue executed successfully but you need to do some more things to actually write back to the OPC Server. 3. SetValue failed silently (which I don't think is the case).

It's important to understand how the DI (Dependency Injection) is working in here, since we/you don't know if your class it's even executing or if the Logger is injected. I would suggest you to improve your question by giving a bit more information of the project structure and the Startup.cs/Program.cs of your program
